# Message after registration in Joomla/VirtueMart

Tags: php, joomla, virtuemart

I am very newbie in Joomla and VirtueMarkt. I have these shop. If i go to registration i have link:

http://myshop.com/index.php?option=com_virtuemart&page=shop.registration&Itemid=1

If all fields are OK then this redirect me to homepage without message, for example "Thanks you for registration.", but if username is already in use then i am redirect to homepage and i have error **This username/password already in use. Please try another.**.
How can i add message if registration is OK?

Comment: You said that if registration is OK that the user sees "Thanks you for registration." right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the code below after body tag on file located at the root of your template.

Code:`<jdoc: include type="message" />`

Generally is on index.php located on "templates/name_of_your_template" folder